# Invalid null character in text to output for Null Java.Lang.Long

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I have a Apache Axis2 Soap Service , that response a Java Object with a Java.Lang.Long field. When the field is `null`, I receive the exception:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid null character in text to output
```

If the field has value, works with no problem.

On the WSDL schema, the field appears as a `xs:long` type, so, I don't know why Axis is throwing this error:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codCustomerNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: NULL is not a valid Long value, your code is trying to parse the value to a Long, but fails. don't try to parse it, unless there 's actually a value in there

Comment: Is a Java Object that is Null, I don't know why Axis is not detecting the field properly.